# Loop through array of objects inside the class

Tags: java

I am having some trouble looping through an array with objects, inside the class. I wrote a little demo here so you can follow:

```
Tank tanks[] = new Tank[2];
tanks[0] = new Tank();
tanks[1] = new Tank();
tanks[0].doStuff(tanks);

doStuff(Tank[] tanks) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tanks.length; i++) {
        if (tanks[i].equals(this)) continue;
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

So, I have an array with the type Tank. Then I call the method doStuff inside the Tank class. The method takes the array and loops through it. And then I want to do stuff to every tank that is not the current instance of the class. I hope you can make sense out of my code and this description.

The problem is that I get nullPointerException for `if (tanks[i].equals(this))`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That code won't compile anyway, as you're trying to treat a single value (`Tank tanks`) as an array. Please edit your question to provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Have you reimplemented equals method? If yes, can you show it? That's the only place I think that this null may be comming from, but only if you reimplemented it and done something wrong. The rest is clean.

Comment: @JonSkeet you can use that syntax to create an array. It's strange, but he declared it as an array in the variable name.

Comment: @RalfHoppen: The code has been edited. The original declaration had `doStuff(Tank tanks)`. It wasn't the call site I was worried about - it was the method declaration. (It's still not a valid declaration as it has no return type, but the error I mentioned before has been fixed.) A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would still be preferable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means that `tanks[i]` is null.  (or that your overridden `equals()` method has a bug)

You need to check for that.

Comment: More likely the latter, given the relatively basic nature of the code provided.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Given that the code provided wouldn't compile (even after being silently edited), I strongly suspect it's not representative of the real code being run.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code:

```
public class Tank {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tank tanks[] = new Tank[2];
    tanks[0] = new Tank();
    tanks[1] = new Tank();
    tanks[0].doStuff(tanks);
  }

  public void doStuff(Tank[] tanks) {
      for (int i = 0; i < tanks.length; i++) {
          if (tanks[i].equals(this)) continue;
          // Do stuff
      }
  }
}
```

No error happens. Therefore, you've probably overridden `.equals`, and that is where the `NullPointerException` is occurring. The other possibility is that your simple example doesn't accurately reflect where your bug is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare the IDs of your object you can use `==` instead of `.equals()`

```
doStuff(Tank tanks) {
  for (int i = 0; i < tanks.length; i++) {
    if (tanks[i] == this) {
        continue;
      }
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```